# I'm building a multiplatform app with SwiftUI in xcode. I want to use realm. It works in iOS App, but it didn't work in MacOS App

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, realm

[image]

error:Failed to login to Realm: The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted

Comment: For macOS targets, you must explicitly enable “Outbound Connections (Client)” on the “Capabilities” tab:

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code as text, using proper code formatting - and not as a screenshot -, in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question so take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 3):

If it’s what I think it is:

For macOS targets, you must explicitly enable “Outbound Connections (Client)” on the “Capabilities” tab:

[image]